# What design pattern did Twig use to implement the Loaders?

Tags: php, design-patterns, abstract-class, twig

I am studying design patterns and in particular the Factory and Abstract Factory patterns. I studied Twig by Fabien Potencier and adapted the way he wrote code for the class `Twig_Loader_Filesystem` for another situation of mine.

Here is how he started the class:

```
class Twig_Loader_Filesystem
    implements Twig_LoaderInterface, Twig_ExistsLoaderInterface
```

I was wondering if the way that Fabien did it for `Twig_Loader_Filesystem` is considered as abstract factory pattern or just a simple abstract design pattern? Because I can tell the use of interface suggests abstract, but I *think* this is not a factory class.

Perhaps he used a factory method elsewhere? What design pattern is used in here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the actual implementation there might be other patterns involved (Factory too), but what you are writing about here is the Strategy pattern.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern

http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/strategy

Strategy pattern is an example of basic abstraction where interchangable classes implement a common interface and encapsulate different algorithms without the client class having to take care or be aware of them.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you happen to see any factory or abstract factory being used in Twig or Symfony components?

Comment: For a start you can look for code that says "Factory": https://github.com/search?q=factory++repo%3Asymfony%2Fsymfony+extension%3A.php&type=Code&ref=advsearch&l= Not all of them are factories, but there are some factories here, for example: Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Encoder/EncoderFactory.php